# jquery find select options attributes

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I know how to get the attributes of an element, using jquery.  But I'm not sure how to do it with the actual options in a select field.

```
<select referenceID="55" name="test" id="test">
  <option value="1">first option</option>
  <option value="2">second option</option>
  <option value="3">third option</option>
</select>
```

To get the referenceID I would just do this:

```
$("#test").attr("referenceID");
```

And when I want to get the value:

```
$("#test").val();
```

But I want to get a little more interesting.  I want to put some specific info into each option:

```
<select name="test" id="test">
  <option value="1" title="something here"*>first option</option>
  <option value="2" title="something else here">second option</option>
  <option value="3" title="another thing here">third option</option>
</select>
```

Is it possible to grab an attribute within the options tags?

I intend to have an onselect function that reads the title tag, and does helps me with some other things.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Presuming you want to find the `title` attribute of the selected option...

```
$('#test option:selected').attr('title');
```

That is, find the descendant element of `#test` that is (a) an option element and (b) [is selected](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector).

If you already have a selection containing `#test`, you can do this with `find`:

```
$('#test').find('option:selected').attr('title');
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're using onchange, you can use like the following :

```
$("#test").change(function(){
    var title =  $(this).find('option:selected').attr('title');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this not work?

```
$("#test").change(function() {

   var title = $(this).attr("title");

});
```